# Read and manipulate spreadsheet in CSV format

Tags: python, csv

This code must print the data, delete a row or column, insert a row or column, change a value in a cell and output the data in CSV format.

I am having trouble with adding a row (add a member) and changing a value in a cell (edit a member).

The add a member error message I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 161, in <module>
    opts[choice](keys, data)
  File "main.py", line 31, in add_member
    newMember = get_info(keys, data)
  File "main.py", line 133, in get_info
    Ind = max([int(k) for k in [data[n]['id'] for n in range(len(data))]]) + 1
  File "main.py", line 133, in <listcomp>
    Ind = max([int(k) for k in [data[n]['id'] for n in range(len(data))]]) + 1
KeyError: 'id'
```

and for editing a member it is a similar error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 161, in <module>
    opts[choice](keys, data)
  File "main.py", line 41, in edit_member
    mem = search(keys, data)
  File "main.py", line 106, in search
    if(D['id'] == chosenResult):
KeyError: 'id'
```

I am stuck at this point and don't see how I can fix this code to get those to work. Any help is appreciated!

```py
import csv

def read_file(path, keys, data):
    #Read .csv file first line to list of keys and remaining lines to list of dictionaries
    with open(path, 'r') as csvFile:
        keys = csvFile.readline().strip().split(',')
        print('\nFile Keys: ', keys, '\n')
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvFile, fieldnames=keys)
        for row in reader:
            print('Row: ', dict(row))
            data.append(dict(row))
        return keys

def write_file(keys, data):
    #Write list of keys to first line and list of dictionaries to remaining lines of file
    with open('CharacterSpreadsheets.csv', 'w') as csvFile:
        writer = csv.DictWriter(csvFile, fieldnames=keys)
        writer.writeheader()
        for D in data:
            writer.writerow(D)

def add_member(keys, data):
    #Add new row with member information to list of dictionaries
    print('\nAdding Member\n')
    newMember = get_info(keys, data)
    data.append(newMember)

def del_member(keys, data):
   print('\nDeleting Member\n')
   data.pop(int(input('Choose Member Number: ')))

def edit_member(keys, data):
    #Search for row and select value to edit
    print('\nSelect Member to edit: ', end='')
    mem = search(keys, data)
    if(mem == -1):
        return
    for i, k in enumerate(keys):
        print('\t' + str(i+1).ljust(4) + k)
    select = int(input('\nSelect value to edit (1 through ' + str(len(keys)) + ') or 0 to abort edit: '))
    if(select < 1 or select > len(keys)):
        return
    print(keys[int(select) - 1], ' selected')
    newVal = input('Enter new Value: ')
    data[mem].update({keys[select - 1]: newVal})

def print_membership(keys, data):
    #Print pretty formatted table of values in list of dictionaries
    colWidth = colSize(keys, data)
    print('\nResult:')
    for d in range(len(data)):
        print('\n\t', end='')
        for i, k in enumerate(keys):
            print(data[d][k].ljust(colWidth[i] + 2), end = ' ')
    print('\n\n')

def add_column(keys, data):
    #Add new column with specified key at specified location in all dictionaries in list
    print('\n\t(0) ', end=' ')
    for i, k in enumerate(keys):
        print(k, "(%d)"%(i + 1), end=' ')
    newKey = input('\n\nEnter Column Label (no Spaces): ')
    default = input('\nEnter Default Value for new column: ')
    pos = input('\nSelect position for new column [0 through %d]: '% (len(keys)))
    for D in data:
        D.update({newKey:default})
    keys.insert(int(pos), newKey)

def del_column(keys, data):
    #Delete column selected by column label (key)
    print('\n\t', end=' ')
    for k in keys:
        print(k, end='  ')
    delKey = input('\n\nEnter Column Name: ')
    if (delKey in keys):
        for D in data:
            D.pop(delKey)
        keys.remove(delKey)
    else:
        print('\nKey Not Found')

def search(keys, data):
    #Search for dictionary according to specified string in selected key
    print('\n')
    for i, k in enumerate(keys):
        print('\t' + str(i+1).ljust(4) + k)
    select = int(input('\nSelect search criteria (1 through '+ str(len(keys)) + ') Enter 0 to abort: '))
    if(select < 1 or select > len(keys)):
        return -1
    print(keys[select - 1], ' selected')
    find = input('Enter ' + keys[int(select) - 1] + ' to search for: ')
    result = []
    for D in data:
        if(find.upper() in D[keys[select - 1]].upper()):
            result.append(D)
    print('\nFound ', len(result), ' results')
    print_membership(keys, result)
    chosenResult = input('Choose result id or 0 to abort search: ')
    for i, D in enumerate(data):
        if(D['id'] == chosenResult):
            return i
    return -1

def look_up(keys, data):
    #Use search function and print one line of formatted table
    mem = search(keys, data)
    if(mem >= 0):
        for k in keys:
            print(data[mem][k], end='   ')
    print('\n\n')

def quit(keys, data):
    #Prompt user to save changes to file and Quit program
    save = input('Save Changes before quitting? [y,n]: ')
    if(save == 'y'):
        write_file(keys, data)
    print('Thank You for using my address book\n')

def menu():
    #Display menu for user options
    print('\nOptions:\n\ta  = add member\n\td  = delete member\n\te  = edit member\n\tdc = delete column\n\t\
ac = add column\n\tp  = print membership\n\ts  = search\n\tw  = write file\n\tq  = quit\n')

def get_info(keys, data):
    #Prompt user for all values to create a new dictionary and return dictionary
    info = {}
    Ind = max([int(k) for k in [data[n]['id'] for n in range(len(data))]]) + 1
    info['id'] = str(Ind)
    for k in keys[1:]:
        info[k] = input('Enter ' + k + ': ')
    return info

def colSize(keys, data):
    #Get list of maximum lengths of values for each key in all dictionaries
    cS = [max([len(data[n][k]) for n in range(len(data))]) for k in keys]
    # print("\nColumn Widths: ", cS)
    return cS

data = []
keys = []

opts = {'a': add_member, 'd': del_member, 'e': edit_member, 'dc': del_column,\
'ac': add_column, 'p': print_membership, 's': look_up, 'w': write_file, 'q': quit}

keys = read_file('CharacterSpreadsheets.csv', keys, data)

print('\n\n')

menu()
choice = ' '
while(choice != 'q'):
    print('Input Options: ', list(opts.keys()))
    choice = input('Choose Option: ')
    if choice in list(opts.keys()):
        opts[choice](keys, data)
    else:
        menu()
```

Comment: Right above line 133, `print data[0]` and show us what that gives.  It likely is a dictionary, but it doesn't have the key `id` for some reason.

Comment: Hi Isabel, would you be able to provide sample input/output text? Thanks!

Comment: Don’t read the header line before creating the DictReader

Comment: Spelling mistake? can you add the header line to the question? formatted as code?

Answer (score 1):

Have you  tried **pandas**, it would make manipulating the csv files way easier
checkout the official docs here https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/index.html
it abstracts all the messy details of parsing data using the csv module and way faster search,deletion and addition of row and columns

Comment: Will this solve the `KeyError` for a key of `'id'`?

Comment: __absolutely__  your column names will be used for selecting columns of interest and apply pandas rich indexing methods  what is required is to load your data and start exploring  `import pandas as pd;df=pd.read_csv("dataset.csv");df.column_name`

Comment: So the resultant DataFrame  is guaranteed to have an `'id'` key?

Comment: yes pandas will add an index to the dataframe when you impoty the data  `# importing pandas package 
import pandas as pd 
  
# making data frame from csv file 
data = pd.read_csv("nba.csv", index_col ="Name") 
  
# retrieving columns by indexing operator 
first = data["Age"] `                                                                                or for row indexing             `# making data frame from csv file 
data = pd.read_csv("nba.csv", index_col ="Name") 
  
# retrieving row by loc method 
first = data.loc["Avery Bradley"] 
second = data.loc["R.J. Hunter"] `

Comment: check this article  on [indexing](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/indexing-and-selecting-data-with-pandas/)

Comment: Are you assuming the actual data has an `'id'` column?

Comment: Pandas automatically assigns a numerical index if you dont specify one when importing your csv file  so if your data has no id column you'll nonetheless have numerical index and you can treat that as an id if you like